# move picture box vb.net mousekeydown and up

Tags: .net, vb.net, picturebox, keydown, keyup

i am in visual basic dot net i have a picture box and i need to move it, the user click and move the mouse and the picturebox need move with it when the user release the mouse  the picture box have location

```
Public Class Form1
Dim punto As New Point()

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
punto = Cursor.Position
PictureBox1.Location = punto
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
punto = Cursor.Position
PictureBox1.Location = punto

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim Offset As Point
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
     Offset = New Point(-e.X, -e.Y)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
     If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
         Dim Pos As Point = Me.PointToClient(MousePosition)
         Pos.Offset(Offset.X, Offset.Y)
         PictureBox1.Location = Pos
     End If
    End Sub
```